# Can't enable iCloud Drive on OS X Sierra

Tags: mac, icloud, macos

Can't enable iCloud Drive on OS X Sierra. Going to `Sys. Preferences > iCloud` , can enable every feature, but not iCloud Drive. Can't enable it and icon has a fade out effect. Tried to log out and login again - didn't worked.

[image: iCloud settings]

What could be the problem? My Mac was issued me by my company - could they block that feature?

macOS Sierra 10.12.5 Beta (16F43c)

Comment: Why do you run a Beta Version? This could be a side effect caused by 10.12.5 Beta.

Answer (score 9):

In case this is your company's computer, it could have been deactivated through a management software, like `jamf`:

https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/20997/disable-icloud-desktop-and-documents-in-sierra

Comment: This might have been better as a comment.  Alternatively, you could consider expanding your answer to explore other possibilities and any potential solutions/workarounds that would remedy the OP's problem.

Comment: Actually, @xanderiel is right. But do you have any idea how to unlock this policy?

Comment: Agree it could also have been a comment. Regarding the OP's question: in case it's regulated through jamf this should be nearly impossible to circumvent. jamf's core business is to enforce company policies so "worthless peons" cannot get around it. It's closely tied to the OS anyway. But, you might simply talk to your corporate IT team to see if there's a way around it.

Comment: while you will not be able to modify jamf's policies, you can simply remove jamf itself from your laptop.

Answer (score 2):

These ports need to be open on your company's firewall/security appliance to allow iCloud in general:

> To allow iCloud to function, Apple has a list of ports which need to be allowed for iCloud to function on your client devices. The ports used by iCloud are:
>
> TCP 25
>
> TCP 80
>
> TCP 443
>
> TCP 587
>
> TCP 993
>
> TCP 5223

See [this Meraki page](https://documentation.meraki.com/zGeneral_Administration/Other_Topics/Whitelisting_Apple_iCloud_services_on_a_restrictive_firewall) for more details. Your company's IT group should be able to tell you if these ports are blocked. Which specific port blocks iCloud Drive is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange indeed. Have you tried booting in Safe mode?

Start up while holding the left shift key.

Comment: didn't help at all. At least I know about the safe mode - thanks!

Comment: iCloud is still not available. I think it was "removed", as I can't find iCloud path lurking through terminal: `$ cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs -bash: cd: /Users/dmitry.mihailov/Library/Mobile`

Answer (score 0):

1. What happen when you try to access via Terminal? [Access iCloud Drive](https://www.clihelp.org/MO00058/access-icloud-drive)
2. Try to access the same via [www.icloud.com](http://www.icloud.com)
3. What about your iPhone? Same issue
4. Try to sign out and sign in again.
5. Anything going on with your Search Domains? [Add Search Domains](https://www.clihelp.org/MO00142/add-search-domains)

Comment: 1. output
2. There are only my photos from iphone and nothing from Mac.
3. iPhone works fine with iCloud.
4. Tried - no results. Will try with safe mode.
5. Search domains - how are they involved here?

Comment: 1. output: `$ cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs
-bash: cd: /Users/dmitry.mihailov/Library/Mobile`

Comment: did you use to pay for more storage and than stop to pay apple? example did you request more GB previously ? I will also try https://getsupport.apple.com/

Comment: I got to the support, they've took remote control of my Mac... and no results. I think may it's because of Beta OS I have installed.